# How to align text to the right one the same line using jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

[image]I am using jquery mobile and I have a question on how to apply css.  I have the image below and I would like the $10 on the same line as the other text, except aligned to the right.

I am used to twitter bootstrap where I would have all of the text on the same row and then have the content sit in different spans (span10 and span2, perhaps).  Any advice on how to do this using jquery mobile?

Code:

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal"> 
            <a class="changePageButton" data-transition="slide">

            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top"><h2>Himalayan Flavors<small> (0.5 mi)</small></h2>
              <span style="float:right"><label for="province">$10</label></span>
              <right><p>$40 for $20</p></right></li> 

            <li class="custom_listview_img" style = "background-image:url('http://c.yipitcdn.com/thumbor/SOWRPRFYvkagojw-sA_VPeSKK_k=/408x357/smart/c.yipitcdn.com/deal/20-to-spend-on-food-and-drink-3761-1374483321.jpg');"></li>
        </a>
        </ul>

    <style>
        .custom_listview_img {
            margin:0px; 
            padding:0px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:100%;
            height:150px;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please add in some code for reference.

Comment: Added the relevant code

Comment: The a attribute should be inside <li> // here is your <a href.... </li>

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery mobile, you can use

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal">
   <a class="changePageButton" data-transition="slide">
   <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top">
        <h2>Himalayan Flavors<small> (0.5 mi)</small></h2>
             <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>$10</strong>PM</p>
             <p>$40 for $20</p>
   </li> 

 </a>    
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZbnZ/